# Move to next unmatched line with vimdiff

Tags: cursor-movement, vimdiff

Is there a way to move to the next unmatched line with in vimdiff? Not "move to the next changed line", but move to the next unmatched line for the current file.

In my case I'm trying to compare two large files, one of which should be practically a subset of the other. What I want to do is to see if there's any lines in the smaller file which are missing in the larger file. I figured I should be able to place my cursor in the larger file, and then directly jump to the next "missing" line annotation.

---

It just so happens that the current files in question are sorted, so I can probably use the "comm" command line utility to find the missing lines, but I was wondering if there's an easy way to do it in vimdiff, particularly if the lines aren't sorted.

Comment: What exactly are unmatched lines? Lines, that are added on the other buffer?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Yes. Lines that are in one file (buffer) which are not in the other file (buffer).

Comment: and you want to move to the added lines in the other buffer? (you cannot move on top of the deleted filler lines)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly what you want and you want to find those lines, that are unique in one buffer and therefore marked as "DiffAdd" in the other buffer.

Unfortunately, there is no native way to do it using the `search()` function, therefore you have to work around it with the following function, that works by searching for a line, that has the "DiffAdd" highlighting.

```
function! NextChange()
    while search('^.*', 'w') > 0
        if synIDattr(diff_hlID(line('.'),col('.')), 'name') is# 'DiffAdd'
            break
        endif
    endwhile
endfunction
com! NextChange :call NextChange()
```

Comment: Does this work for removals and changes, too?

Comment: You might need to search for 'DiffChange' highlighting as well